# Line-configuration in algebraic hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are working on $\mathbb{C}^3$ (so that maybe this is more appealing to algebraic geometers) and we are given an algebraic equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ of degree $n\geq 3$ defining some smooth hypersurface (irreducible if you like). I am interested in the possible line-configurations on $F$. Specifically I am interested in the existence (or non-existence) of some non-trivial bound on the number of lines on $F$ that can meet a given line $\ell$ also contained in $F$. Let me explain myself providing some motivation: if $n=3$ it is well-known (or it seems so) that a line in a cubic can meet no more than 10 other lines on it. (I understand this to be a non-trivial result since it does contain 27 lines.) There are other results on this direction due to Segre (1943) for quartics: in that paper there is a quadratic (on the degree $n$) bound on the number of lines such a hypersurface can contain that also has been (sharply) studied by Boissière and Sarti (2006). What I would like to hear about is that there is some bound depending, say, linearly on $n$ that can be achieved by some technique I am not aware of or maybe this is just a research level problem in algebraic geometry (a field I am not quite acquainted with) and not a "probably well-known" fact (as I feel it should probably be). I have tried in vain to locate anything similar in the literature, I hope you can provide if not an answer some references towards it. Thank you! :)

Comment: This seems quite difficult. Accidentally, if you mean lines meeting a given one, Segre's bound of 18 for quartics is wrong: the true bound is 20.

Comment: (You are right, Alex. That's why I didn't wrote anything about it specificically; in fact, that doesn't really bother me since I am more interested in the asymptotics as a function on $n$ than in the specific exact values for each $n$. In that sense it might be easier to handle. In any case thank you for the observation.)

Comment: (I changed "any given line $\ell$" by "a given line $\ell$" so that now I hope it is clearer. What I meant was that the bound should be thought of as uniform on the choice of the line $\ell$. I hope now it is well-posed. So, again, you are right! That's what I meant, thank you!)